# connectedCallback vs window.load

Tags: javascript, custom-element

What event comes first if custom element is included in plain HTML body?

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('test');

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  elem.innerHTML = 'window.load';
});

class myDiv extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    elem.innerHTML = 'connectedCallback';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-div', myDiv);
```

```html
<my-div id="test"></my-div>
```

Looks like `window.load` always comes last.

Comment: Yes you are correct `window.load` occurs when everything but the kitchen sink has been loaded. https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was stated by @zer00ne the general rule is that `windows.onload` is called last as long as everything is already on the page.

If you create elements dynamically then their `constructor` and `connectedCallback` functions will be called after `window.onload`.

Also if you lazy load any of your components then they will run after `window.onload` even if you place their HTML in the page prior to the trigger of `window.onload`.

```js
    const loaded = msg => () => console.log(msg);

    window.onload = loaded('window.onload');

    class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        loaded('MyEl.constructor')();
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        loaded('MyEl.connectedCallback')();
      }
    }

    customElements.define('my-el', MyEl);

    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('About to create element');
      var newEl = document.createElement('my-el');
      console.log('About to add element to body');
      document.body.appendChild(newEl);
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('About to create new script tag');
      newEl = document.createElement('script');
      newEl.textContent = `
      class MyEl2 extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super();
          loaded('MyEl2.constructor')();
        }

        connectedCallback() {
          loaded('MyEl2.connectedCallback')();
        }
      }

      customElements.define('my-el-2', MyEl2);
      `;
      console.log('About to add script element to body');
      document.body.appendChild(newEl);
    }, 2000);
```

```html
    <my-el></my-el>
    <my-el-2></my-el-2>
```